# Dealing with multiple JFrames

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have a class which creates a JFrame. When I click on a button in the JFrame, another JFrame in a different class opens up.

Now, when I close the second JFrame, even the first one closes up. Any ideas on preventing this? I want the first frame to remain visible.

Comment: My crystal ball says you should fix something at line 157.

Comment: Questions like these need to include an [MCVE] or an [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org). Without that, it's like JB said, we'd need a crystal ball to help you.

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
JFrame.dispose()
```

on the second JFrame.

Also when using `setDefaultCloseOperation() //this is what happens when you press x on window.`
 avoid EXIT_ON_CLOSE and use DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE.

PS:Where is the code?  :P

Comment: Thanks a lot bro! PS:I didn't think that the code was necessary.Well, I guess I learn't my lesson.